# Function does not execute onPressed in ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a reusable button widget and when I pass in the function for the onPressed of the ElevatedButton this doesn't get executed.

Note, the other places that I use this onPressed to navigate works

Places where I use the onPressed and works

```
 BlackButton(
          text: 'Create offer',
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'createOfferFighter'), //this works
        ),
```

Place where I execute a function - This widget is in a stateful parent widget

```
  BlackRoundedButton(
                    isLoading: false 
                    text: submitButton,
                    onPressed: () =>
                        createOffer() //doesn't print anything
                  ),
```

The createOffer() function

```
void createOffer() {
    print('casfas');
  }
```

Reusable button widget:

```
class BlackButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onPressed;

  final String text;

  const BlackButton({Key? key, required this.onPressed, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 230,
      height: 60,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [containerShadowRed]),
        child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () => onPressed(),
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlackButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  final String text;

  const BlackButton({Key? key, required this.onPressed, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 230,
      height: 60,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [containerShadowRed]),
        child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This should print the createOffer():

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlackButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onPressed;

  final String text;

  const BlackButton({Key? key, required this.onPressed, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 230,
      height: 60,
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: []),
        child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a pair of () where I have my custom button widget

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 230,
      height: 60,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [containerShadowRed]),
        child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.black),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () => onPressed(), //() were missing next to onPressed
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you did actually show the implementation of `BlackRoundedButton` instead of `BlackButton` in the question, since that's the one with the problem